# Emailer's Media Queries Not Working on Pixel Android 7 Device

Tags: responsive-design, html-email

I've developed a responsive emailer which works perfectly on all devices except that it doesn't work on Pixel Android 7 device.

It simply discards media queries and displays the desktop version of the emailer.

What could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: Do you mean you designed a html page or are you referring to the email itself or something else?

Comment: I've developed HTML email using only table structure

Comment: Emails are tricky, while I don't know the android device but if youa re viewing an email on it and the media queries don't work, then it probably does not allow media queries in emails. Unless there is some kind of setting on the device to allow it

Comment: It seems that there has to be some way for media query to make it work on pixel devices especially! or the pixel device has more resolution, hence it is taking desktop version and thus discarding media queries

Comment: Well you can verify that part by adding a desktop media query and see if ti works on the device, if it doesn't then you will know. How are you checking this email? Using an app? if so then you are at the mercy of the app

Comment: I'm checking on Litmus and Email on Acid tool

Comment: You would have to google those or google the device and media queries. It's not a surprise that media queries don't work in emails. It might be a setting you can change for those app to allow better email support but if it doesn't then you are sol

Comment: Which email client on Pixel Android 7 are you using? Android has been pushing people to use GMail app for all emails and most recent version of Gmail app support media queries.

Comment: Using a non-gmail address in the Gmail app will cause the stylesheet to be removed

Comment: Or if there's an error in the stylesheet Gmail will also remove it.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with? "doesn't work" is *not* a useful problem description.

Comment: @Nag, post your html code along with the media queries. You say it works fine on other clients. Maybe you missed something.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, Android does not support `@media` queries. Some versions of Gmail do not support them and neither does Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016.

- https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/

Comment: If it's a Pixel it'll be using Gmail by default, which does support media queries. So could be something else such as a CSS error or non-gmail address.

Comment: @Gwesolo, that's a great point. Without knowing the devices Nag is using or seeing the code, there's no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @gwally's answer, some Android clients don't support media queries. If the email client in question ***is* Gmail**, it *still* might not support media queries depending on what Gmail product is being tested.

While Gmail rolled out major media query support in 2016, the update does not cover every Gmail product. Rémi Parmentier did [a fantastic breakdown of Gmail's media query support](https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/trying-to-make-sense-of-gmail-css-support-after-the-2016-update-53c15151063a):

[image]

In addition to the link @gwally posted, [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/) has a good breakdown of support.

---

So if, for instance, your Pixel phone is using Gmail with a POP/IMAP email, media queries won't work and we should expect to see a shrunken version of the desktop version. **Hybrid email design** can make an email layout stack in mobile clients that don't support media queries. [Here's a primer](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-responsive-and-hybrid-email-design) if this is something you'd like to look into.